# Is the line height property inherited from the body

Tags: css, inheritance, fonts

I have some html as below- nothing fancy- just a div and a span

```
<div id="container">Some text to affect the width</div>
<span>A</span>
```

I'm using [eric meyer's css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). One of the things that he is doing is setting the line-height of the body to 1. Also, he is setting the font: inherit; for every element.

Then, I have a few other styles for the html elements above as follows:

```
body{background:#912FFF}
    #container{background-color:#EDC1C1; width:150px;}
    span{background-color:#35D9C4;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/probosckie/5pb4794u/

The problem is that my span is overlapping with the div. If I zoom into the page it is all the more evident.

Im guessing is that line-height set to 1 and the font set to inherit is messing this up. Can someone please confirm on this??

Comment: try span{ display:block; clear:both;}

Comment: @prabhas http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/line-height all you need to know about line height !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `line-height:normal;` in your `body` element. Setting the line-height to a lower value than its text height will cause overlapping.

Comment: yes this works! Can I also just set the line height of the body to normal in meyer's reset

Comment: That's what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly inline element's padding and margins aren't designed for exact pixel layouts, but for the flow of text. In this case You should use a div instead of the span element or put the span inside a div.